# What to do with the Id returned by AppointmentStore.ShowEditNewAppointmentAsync() when user creates a recurring appointment

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, windows-runtime

I create an Appointment object and then call

`var result = AppointmentStore.ShowEditNewAppointmentAsync(appointment);`

After the user hits "Accept" button on the Popup, `result` variable has the Local Id of the newly created calendar appointment (the documentation says that it is a Roaming Id but that is an error in the documentation) and so I can do `AppointmentStore.GetAppointmentAsync(result);` and I get the newly created calendar appointment.

The problem is that if the user creates a recurring appointment, the `result` variable contains an Id but doing `AppointmentStore.GetAppointmentAsync(result);` returns null... I even tried to convert this Id in a local Id using `AppointmentStore.FindLocalIdsFromRoamingIdAsync(result);` but the returned list of local Ids is empty...

How can I get the newly created appointment or list of appointments (since it is recurring)?

Comment: Can you share the complete code, I need to reproduce this problem and know the app's target version and min version.